# How to separate two normal distributions which are scores of a machine learning model?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, scoring-rules

[image]

Considering I have a machine learning model that predicts the matching score of two entities. The lower the score is the more different the two entities are and vice versa.

`Labels` : `0` = **no match**; `1` = **match**

From the figure, as you can see there is a good overlap between the two normal distributions (score for label 0 and score for label 1).

Is there any statistical method / mathematical device / machine learning model that can separate (somewhat) the two distributions so that I can get a better performance metric / Equal error rate?

What I want is to transform my current scores so that they are more separable and the error is minimum. At the moment, for the overlapping region, I will predict either label 0 or 1 based on a threshold. If I set a threshold of 0.25, I will be able to correctly predict most of the non-match scenarios but will miss a lot of the matches and vice versa.

*Note:* I have an audio dataset, where I have trained a deep neural network (RawNet) to predict if the two audios match (come from the same source or not). It's a slight variation of the speaker recognition task. The model predicts an embedding and I take the cosine similarity of the embeddings as a score.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit? What exactly is the data you have available to you?

Comment: Sure, @mkt I have an audio dataset, where I have trained a deep neural network (RawNet) to predict if the two audios match (come from the same source or not). It's a slight variation of the speaker recognition task. The model predicts an embedding and I take the cosine similarity of the embeddings as a score.

Comment: Please edit that information into the question. Also - it's still not clear exactly what you want to do. Do you just want some method that can distinguish between two overlapping normal(ish) distributions? Why is this useful since those two distributions are already of model predictions?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @mkt True, the question is probably not properly phrased, tried to add more relevant details. I just want a transformation function, which will take my scores and make them more separable.

Comment: I still don't fully understand this, but Gaussian mixture models may be helpful to you.

Comment: Note that the orange distribution is notably non-normal, particularly in the region of overlap. If Whether this is a problem with the underlying NN predictions or a true feature is worth considering, as it will pose problems for any mixture distribution fitting.